# How to make a histogram with labels in Y and with the frequency next to the bars using big dataset?

Tags: python, matplotlib, collections, histogram

I am trying to make a **histogram** for a database of more than 56,640 words.

I want to show the 200 or more frequent words, without them being coupled, that is, they are legible on the Y axis. In addition, the frequency of each word is next the bars corresponding to each word.

I guess the words are coupled (and unreadable), because the size of the screen, but I guess a solution for this could be implement a range:

- E.g.: going from 100 to 200 most common words `histogram(word_index, 100, 200)`.

**Code:**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter

def histogram(word_list, n):
  n = n # this is necessary, otherwise the parameter will not be recognize.
  counts = dict(Counter(word_list).most_common(n))
  labels, values = zip(*counts.items())

  # sort the values in descending order
  indSort = np.argsort(values)[::-1]

  # rearrange the data
  labels = np.array(labels)[indSort]
  values = np.array(values)[indSort]

  indexes = np.arange(len(labels))

  # figure configuration
  plt.figure(figsize = (15, 4))
  bar_width = 0.35
  plt.bar(indexes, values, color = 'r')

  # add labels
  plt.xticks((indexes + bar_width), labels, rotation = 'vertical', color = 'white')
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.show()

hitogram(word_index, 201)
```

**Actual output:**
[image: actual output]

**Expected output:**

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is easier if you use `plot.barh()` method from `pandas` Series.

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
text = """
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, aenean volutpat nam nulla ac ipsum, iaculis ultrices egestas, ac lacus fringilla ante, leo id ac conubia, sit justo suspendisse eu consectetuer. Rutrum nunc, maecenas quisque accumsan lobortis commodo sit, dui est molestie nunc imperdiet, donec condimentum justo neque ut quis, lorem aliquet enim vehicula sapien enim. Bibendum tempus faucibus dolor quis vestibulum, amet ligula sem phasellus hendrerit, ultrices voluptas per massa, arcu lectus vel, laoreet tincidunt est turpis. Senectus amet molestie est risus velit turpis, id aliquam, ipsum tristique quam phasellus purus, vel magna eget maecenas velit mattis. Felis nulla risus condimentum ipsum curabitur, curae quis, cursus ullamcorper luctus mattis ut, nunc quisque enim faucibus sem, quis feugiat purus condimentum tincidunt id. Ultricies cras fusce nunc sagittis arcu ut. Enim molestie porttitor, cras leo et. Eu bibendum adipiscing convallis etiam, velit volutpat amet accumsan non non cursus. Ut in mauris sodales leo duis, vitae aliquam accumsan posuere venenatis. Tellus ante id suspendisse, imperdiet sed at vel, ipsum magna, cum dolor curabitur, nunc omnis mauris elit. Urna quisque etiam accumsan leo, dictum massa nibh, eu laoreet. Nulla justo, consectetuer eros, ac mi condimentum purus.
Consectetuer vestibulum at, nulla per duis eget, mauris odio ac vitae, tincidunt risus tincidunt in massa nisl. Quod eu pede erat maecenas dui, suspendisse ipsum rhoncus sed purus at, dui integer nec quam. Ut et cursus, arcu ligula volutpat, et eleifend id montes bibendum metus integer. Massa urna ante sodales sodales etiam, sed a urna aliquam vitae lectus vel, aliquam tellus nulla massa sed, molestie ante ligula quam aliquet proin sed, pede pellentesque elit vel urna urna. Venenatis enim velit amet dictum. Nec enim pretium enim amet lectus sed, dignissim lectus id vel sed, qui mollis mattis pede viverra sit ipsum. Mattis massa vel accumsan, ridiculus orci, ullamcorper enim tristique aliquam eget ridiculus turpis, duis et at natus libero, non convallis sed vel molestie risus. Phasellus non amet vitae odio egestas tincidunt, urna quis etiam eros sollicitudin, quaerat pede platea maecenas aliquam et imperdiet. Curabitur volutpat fusce. Luctus massa sollicitudin venenatis litora, neque nec tortor vel donec in, mi interdum eget vestibulum, eget amet curabitur molestie gravida, mi vivamus euismod.
Dictumst augue id, justo turpis, cras eu placerat accumsan deserunt ac, volutpat quis nunc accumsan risus laoreet, proin reprehenderit. Urna nunc elit velit diam, gravida sed quis eget. Erat morbi wisi aenean amet adipiscing, ut aliquet commodo, quis odio aenean aliquam nulla augue porta, amet ante tincidunt mi ipsum tellus mollis, lacus suspendisse. Cum et est interdum velit semper pellentesque, est dui laoreet in nunc magna, quis ante volutpat duis est, ligula a ridiculus, quam pellentesque omnis pellentesque. Sodales suspendisse sed at tellus, sit aliquam proin libero, vitae sed doloribus tellus. Morbi libero ipsum, placerat amet vel, magna dignissim pellentesque velit non erat. Neque urna dolor, quam suspendisse scelerisque turpis nulla dui, tortor amet praesent quisque, senectus aliquam urna cum.
Ullamcorper mollis dapibus aenean in, nulla vivamus interdum a nam vestibulum sodales, sed amet nulla integer, luctus orci. Facilisis auctor mauris, non lorem tellus lorem, in habitasse. Ut euismod tellus eros, metus vel risus, turpis non in augue arcu, neque vivamus etiam, porttitor dui vitae sociosqu libero. Ornare ultrices etiam suspendisse, molestie fringilla hendrerit quisque tincidunt. Consectetuer pellentesque in eu nibh, tortor non at mollis suspendisse ullamcorper ipsum. Nec eu aliquam tincidunt hymenaeos nonummy mollis, id ac diam sapien felis, et est quis, ante vivamus rutrum illo feugiat vitae integer. Vestibulum nec dignissim litora, lobortis mauris ac facilisi, pede orci interdum, sagittis et, ultricies semper in sed nulla nulla eget. Amet pede, euismod consectetur, eu erat molestie tempor gravida diamlorem, pede hendrerit duis fermentum turpis in ut, placerat id urna dapibus vivamus. Lobortis turpis in tristique potenti felis amet. Id libero vitae ipsum sodales lacinia sociis, aliquam eros.
"""
words = text.split()
counts = Counter(words)
serie = pd.Series(counts) # this convert dictionary to pandas Series object
N = 50 # number of words to plot
first_N = serie.sort_values().tail(N) # sort the values (in ascending order) of the serie and select the N most frequent words
ax = first_N.plot.barh(figsize=(8, 16)) # make the horizontal bar plot, set the size of thefigure
i = 0 
xoffset = 0.1 # change this value to adjust the text label
for v in first_N.values:
    # adds the text next to each bar
    ax.text(y=i, x=v + xoffset, s=v, ha='left', va='center') 
    i += 1
```

Comment: can add more commets in your code to explain me better how it works? I don't know how to use many of the methods from pandas that you are using. Usually I use matplotlib to make graphs.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you didn't use `Counter(word_list).most_common(n)`

Comment: No usé `Counter(word_list).most_common(n)` porque `.tail(N)` hace la misma función, pero solo calculas las frecuencias una sola vez.  Con `Counter(word_list).most_common(n)` tendrías que calcular las frecuencias cada vez que cambias n, lo cual es menos eficiente.

Comment: `Pandas` use  `matplotlib` as backend, the syntax is slightly different, but you will get the same plots with almost the same functions.